# HTMLCollection.namedItem() behavior difference between Forefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, google-chrome

[DOM4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-htmlcollection)  says namedItem() should returns the first element with ID or name from the collection.

I observed that Firefox behaves correctly but chrome returns all matching Element objects inside a NodeList object.

Does chrome violate the standard in terms of namedItem() method?

```
var hc = document.images
hc.length; //3
hc.namedItem("logo"); // 2 images with name="logo"

Object.prototype.toString.call(hc.namedItem("logo"))

Firefox -> "[object HTMLImageElement]"
Chrome ->  "[object NodeList]"
```

Comment: File a bug report with chrome. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Thanks reported http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122581&thanks=122581&ts=1333912131

Comment: @Praveen: When filing a bug, I'd recommend following their required structure for reporting very closely.

Comment: sure, next time i will follow the reporting pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Chrome is violating the standard here.